# Get Total number of rows in CSV with Super CSV

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I need to get access to the number of rows for a CSV being processed but it seems Super CSV does not have an out-of-the-box option.

The code below seems to do the trick:

```
private int getCsvFileTotalRows(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    int totalRows = 0;
    BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream, BOMS);
    Reader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bomInputStream,  StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    CsvMapReader csvMapReader = new CsvMapReader(fileReader, CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);
    String[] headers = csvMapReader.getHeader(true);
    
    while (csvMapReader.read(headers) != null) {
        totalRows++;
    }
    return totalRows;
}
```

But the problem is that there is already code in place which is creating a CsvMapReader based on an inputStream to process the file, so adding the method above does not work since the CsvMapReader instance was already created with the same inputStream instance I am trying to use in the method above.

How can I achieve this with Super CSV?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880873/retrieve-row-number-with-supercsv